# Incorporation of YUI 3 in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yui, yui3

I was wondering if any effort has been made towards integration of YUI3 with rails asset pipeline.

By integration, I don't just mean a couple of helpers for including the library but rather a complete integration of YUI module loader.

I'll elaborate the idea in detail:

- Currently, developers developing modules using YUI rely on Ant tasks for concatenating the module components and wrapping them up with some associated metadata and generating target files ( and optionally minifying and running jslint).
- Also, when fetching the modules, the YUI loader calculates the module dependencies and generates a single file comprising of all the dependencies which havent been included already in the page. I was wondering if the whole functionality could be seamlessly integrated into the Asset pipeline of rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Shifter: blazingly fast yui builder](http://yui.github.com/shifter/)
- [YUI-rails: No-hassle integration of YUI with the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline.](https://github.com/nextmat/yui-rails)
- [A bunch of helpers](https://github.com/johnnyiller/yui-on-rails)

Shifter is DIY, but at least you can stop using Ant for concat.

Comment: Shifter is interesting - while I was looking forward to a solution that could automate the generation of builds on an on-the-fly basis, Shifter would be the next best thing.